# How to go up one level in helm find files

Tags: helm

With `C-x C-f` Helm tells me I can go up one level with `C-|` or possibly `C-I`.

[image]

However, when I try either, I get the following behavior instead:

`C-I`

Selects the highlighted file.  It does not go up one level.

`C-|`

[image]

So I guess it was supposed to be `C-I` but that isn't doing what is advertised.  How can I go up one level?

Comment: That's a lowercase L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually "L" in lower case.

You should set the default font to a monospace one, such as DejaVu Sans Mono, Hack, Noto Sans Mono, Source Code Pro, etc. They were designed to make code clearer to avoid confusion like this.